# Add blank column to query

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

Is there a way to add a blank column to a query in Query Studio?  I tried to use a calculation on an existing column but the only options that I get are for First Characters, Last Characters, Concatenation, and Remove Trailing Spaces.  None of these options allow you to enter a decode, case or IF statement.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `If(0<>0) then ("") else("")` ? You may need to [edit the calculation](http://www.cognoise.com/index.php?topic=24427.0) outside of Query Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack as Query Studio is really all about making it easy to get data and doing anything with layout is really a job for Report Studio, but you can do the following:

a) create a calculated column on a text field. Select 'Concatenation' as the operation and put a space as the preceding text. Click ok

b1) right-click on the new column and select 'Format', then 'Text' and enter 1 for the number of characters

or

b2) create another calculated column from the first calculated column, set it to 'first characters' and enter 1 for the number of characters. The first calculated column can now be deleted.

Both of these approaches will give a column that only contains a single space - not *actually* blank but close enough for most purposes. The first approach is a little quicker but may result in the text still existing in some output versions (e.g. csv) - I'd need to do more testing to confirm.

The column title can be edited (to be set to blank) by double clicking it, of course.